# cluster block exception for system index of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_analytics_8.11.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_analytics_8.11.4_001\",\"id\":\"dashboard:ee798f25-ae50-5350-ad24-9d348c8163fc\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_analytics_8.11.4_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];\"},\"status\":403},{\"index\":\".kibana_analytics_8.11.4_001\",\"id\":\"dashboard:345\"
```

Disk space is less then 80% and cluster setting info looks fine.

```
curl -k -u admin:admin -X GET "https://IP:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

output:

```
{
  "persistent":{},
  "transient":{}
}
```

why kibana index giving error and how to solve this issue. please reply soon

I am doing upgrade from 7.17 to 8.11 that time i am facing these issues

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the issue check the following API call results.

1. check if the index is read only => `GET .kibana_analytics_8.11.4_001/_settings?flat_settings`
2. check the disk usage => `GET _cat/allocation?v`

You can also check and edit the index settings from `kibana => stack management => index management`
[image]